# How do I define a from method to convert the error in a foreign result type?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have a pair of `Result` type aliases, `AResult` and `BResult`. `AResult` is from another crate, and embeds its own error type `AError`. I have my result (`BResult`) and I want to convert errors from `AError` to `BError` so I can embed them in the `BResults` that I return.

[TIO demo](https://tio.run/##bZBBasMwFET3PsU0KwnSLpK2CzcNxJAeID2AUYoEAsk2X1IgBJ/dlSW1JG12YubN/EEUnJ8m5yl8eez2RD2xsF7xt6poTdb063PU/HmQ2B2kC8bjHfmxYXyZk9tCNHeI5oeotB0MPqi3m5KC6qncwaUCVAcVbaa9tHUZxfG4xac0KhFAMiEc5mFRGavxpjkfLtVlzp3u7Pwtn80nK4ZWErE8rK7n2O@lWGOF7hjPCSM9KFW1wrUC9dUnxTh7yV/6jzxG/yqXCK0SNMdOwgTJb5hjmYiBdOcf2OIyLpbIYIrHedP0DQ)

```
struct AError(u32);
struct BError(i64);
type AResult = Result<(), AError>;
type BResult = Result<(), BError>;

impl From<AError> for BError {
    fn from(item: AError) -> Self {
        (item as i64)
    }
}

impl From<AResult> for BResult {
    fn from(item: AResult) -> Self {
        item.map_err(BError::from)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let result_as_a: AResult = Err(5u32);
    let result_as_b = result_as_a;
    if let Err(value) = result_as_b {
        print!("{}", value);
    }
}
```

I have defined a conversion for the errors from `AError` to `BError` (`impl From<AError> for BError { ... }`) and I'm trying to define a conversion for the Result which uses it, thinking I could do:

```
impl From<AResult> for BResult {
    fn from(item: AResult) -> Self {
        item.map_err(BError::from)
    }
}
```

But Rust complains that I can't define things from another crate:

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
  --> src/main.rs:12:1
   |
12 | impl From<AResult> for BResult {
   | ^^^^^-------------^^^^^-------
   | |    |                 |
   | |    |                 `std::result::Result` is not defined in the current crate
   | |    `std::result::Result` is not defined in the current crate
   | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
   |
   = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

I'm trying to define an implementation on `BResult`, not `AResult`?!

Am I doing something very stupid? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The duplicates [applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=47fe3acb2e36ff44f5a63302b774680e) and a more [idiomatic version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1917376055e4fc55ed16a9ecc4b16018). TL;DR: just define the conversion between error types, not the result aliases.